# update query with link to an image

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my database I have this:

```
<p>Evento de Natal <img alt="" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-kGiurC1ZAYY/TtxsnlfGfOI/AAAAAAAAAZA/A_QbRtqNnJU/s1600/40arvoresnatalmagiagifs.gif" style="float:right; height:199px; width:200px" /></p>
```

When I insert this code in DB works fine.
But when I try to update the DB with the same code with a function to update, it gives the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mktyw.png

It is recommended not directly insert HTML in the database? How do I do that?
Here are my functions to insert and update.

```
    public function insertNew($data) {
    $this->db->insert('noticias', $data);
    redirect(site_url('/') . 'admin/');
}
```

> ```
> public function updateNew($id, $title, $noticia, $event) {
>     $this->db->query('UPDATE noticias SET title="' . $title . '" , noticia="' . $noticia . '", event="' . $event . '" WHERE id= "' . $id . '"');
>     redirect(site_url('/') . 'admin/all_news');
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes. But If you use the built in `insert` function of codeigniter why not also use its `update` function:

```
public function updateNew($id, $title, $noticia, $event) {
    $data = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'noticia' => $noticia,
        'event' => $event
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('noticias', $data); 

    redirect(site_url('/') . 'admin/all_news');
}
```

Im pretty sure that when it works with the insert function, codeigniter will do the escaping for you in update too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the $this->db->insert method does proper string escaping whereas the raw query you're passing as parameter for $this->db->query does not.

Are you sure that $this->db doesn't include an update or replace method? If it doesn't, you should add them. You can base it on the current insert method and modify it as you see fit.

Comment: Hum... I see what you mean ... Never thought about it. I'll check more carefully.